# Add or subtract from sum based on type of vote in a mysql sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got my table like this called `votes`

```
"id"    "votedElm"  "voteType"  "voteProcessed" "country"
"1"         "4" "0" "0" "US"
"2"         "5" "0" "0" "US"
"3"         "6" "1" "0" "US"
"4"         "8" "0" "0" "US"
"5"         "9" "0" "0" "US"
"6"         "10"    "0" "0" "US"
"7"         "10"    "0" "0" "US"
"8"         "10"    "0" "0" "US"
"9"         "8" "1" "0" "US"
"10"    "9" "1" "0" "US"
"11"    "20"    "1" "0" "US"
"12"    "10"    "1" "0" "US"
"13"    "10"    "1" "0" "US"
"14"    "20"    "0" "0" "US"
"15"    "22"    "0" "0" "US"
"16"    "20"    "0" "0" "US"
"17"    "21"    "0" "0" "US"
"18"    "10"    "0" "0" "US"
"19"    "10"    "0" "0" "US"
"20"    "20"    "0" "0" "US"
"21"    "21"    "0" "0" "US"
"22"    "22"    "0" "0" "US"
"23"    "22"    "0" "0" "US"
"24"    "22"    "1" "0" "US"
```

I use this sql to get distinct like and sum from it:
`select votedElm, count(votedElm) from votes where country = 'US' and voteType = 0 group by votedElm;`

However, in that table, I have `voteType 0 and 1`. `0`is a `+` vote and `1` is a `-` vote.

In the same sql can the `+` votes be added and the `-` votes be deducted from the sum? Instead of having 2 different queries for this?

Hoe can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, like this:

```
SELECT
  votedElm,
  SUM(CASE WHEN voteType = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Totalcount 
FROM votes 
WHERE country = 'US'
GROUP BY votedElm;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a0d/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT votedElm, count(votedElm), 
    SUM(IF(voteType = 0, 1, -1)) AS totalVotes
FROM votes 
WHERE country = 'US' and voteType = 0 
GROUP BY votedElm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT votedElm,SUM(CASE WHEN voteType = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '-1' END) AS count 
FROM `votes` 
WHERE country = 'US' and voteType = '0' 
GROUP BY votedElm;
```

or you can try like

```
$sql1 = "SELECT SUM(votedElm) AS count 
FROM `votes` 
WHERE country = 'US' and voteType = '0' 
GROUP BY votedElm";
$res1 = my_sql_query($sql1);
```

and

```
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(votedElm) AS count 
FROM `votes` 
WHERE country = 'US' and voteType = '1' 
GROUP BY votedElm";
$res2 = my_sql_query($sql2);
```

then

```
$res = $res1[0]['count'] - $res2[0]['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution

```
SELECT
  votedElm,
  SUM(CASE WHEN voteType = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Totalcount 
FROM votes 
WHERE country = 'US'
GROUP BY votedElm;
```